# Couchbase: using QueryAsync<string>(query) fails with "Error reading string. Unexpected token"

Tags: json, couchbase

When using Couchbase generic QueryAsync, I was hoping to get a normal, un-parsed, string back instead of a JSON parsed string.

However, when making this call, it indeed seems that Couchbase SDK for .NET uses Newtonsoft anyways, and tries to intepret it as JSON (it is a valid JSON string by the way!):

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM myCollection WHERE id = {r.Next(1, 100000)}";
await scope.QueryAsync<string>(query); // <-- fails here
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading string. Unexpected
> token: StartObject. Path '', line 6, position 1.'

If I instead do this, it works well and JSON is correctly parsed (all documents from myCollection are valid JSON strings):

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM myCollection WHERE id = {r.Next(1, 100000)}";
await scope.QueryAsync<JObject>(query); // <-- No problem
```

-- EDIT --

I also tried they Keu Value operation instead:

```
var result = await collection.GetAsync(key);
var content = result.ContentAs<string>(); // <-- fails here with same error
```

Also using this approach, that I just [copied from here](https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/current/howtos/kv-operations.html), fails.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered
> while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

The JSON is correct though, and I have verified in different parsers.

Isn't it possible to retrieve raw, unparsed, data from Couchbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this on Couchbase forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value-when-using-var-result-data-contentas-string/28260):

> When using SDK 3.x when trying to get a JSON document from Couchbase
> and using var result = data.ContentAs(); It always return this
> error message: “Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:
> {. Path ‘’, line 1, position 1.”

The solution presented there is very convoluted and complex, and strikes me as counter-intuitive:

JMorris writes:

> Hi @Brian_Davis -
>
> The Transcoder API was redesigned in SDK3; its now much more
> specialized and this type of conversion doesn’t work with the default
> JsonTranscoder. Fortunately, we do have another transcoder which
> mimics the sdk2 behavior called the LegacyTranscoder which should be
> able to handle this for you.

And the convoluted solution seems to be to pass a Transcoder into the options of each call:

```
var result = await collection.GetAsync(key, options: new GetOptions().Transcoder(new LegacyTranscoder()));
var content = result.ContentAs<string>();
```